# Is it possible to put a HTTP outbound gateway into chain?

Tags: spring-integration

I try to put http:outbound-gateway  into a chain, but met exceptions in runtime, may I know can I put http outbound gateway into chain

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The 'request-channel' attribute isn't allowed for a nested (e.g. inside a <chain/>) endpoint element: 'http:outbound-gateway'.
```

but when I removed attribute 'request-channel', IDE told me this is a mandatory attribute.

here is my configuration:

```
<int:chain  input-channel="requestChannel"
            output-channel="requestChannel2">
    <http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel2"  expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           url="http://localhost:8080/postService/postwithparm"
                           http-method="POST"
                           extract-request-payload="true">
    </http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request-channel` is an input for that Gateway. But since it is already n the chain that is already this component to wire channel adapters together and we can't effect it with our own channels.

So, the way to go without `request-channel` is correct. That's just your IDE doesn't support the proper behavior.